# trying to use sigusr1 to stop and continue a program

Tags: c, signals, posix

i'm trying to use sigusr1 to stop and continue a cycle .

here is what i tried

```
volatile sig_atomic_t  condition = 0;

void display_message(int s) {
   if(condition==0){
    printf("%d\n",condition );
    kill(getpid(),SIGSTOP);
    }
    if(condition==1){ 
        printf("%d\n",condition );
    kill(getpid(),SIGCONT);
    }  
    ++condition;
    condition%=2;  
}

int main(void) {

    signal(SIGUSR1,display_message);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("%d \n",getpid());
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when i type kill -USR1 pidnumber  i stop the cycle but when i retype it .i can't continue it

Comment: from the MAN page for `signal`:  *The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also var‐
       ied historically across different versions of Linux.   Avoid  its  use:
       use sigaction(2) instead.*

Comment: the are a large number of functions that are NOT signal safe so should not be used in signal handler function.  the function: `printf()` is one of the functions that should not be used.

Comment: even without printf it doesnt work i just used it to check if "condition" changes

Comment: Suggest using: `write( 1, "message\n" );` inside a signal handler.

Comment: regarding: `void display_message(int s) {`  this function does not cleanly compile.  The compiler outputs the message about an unused parameter.  Suggest either check the parameter for SIGUSR1 or the first line in the body of the function should be: `(void)s;`

Comment: You might want to read the MAN page `(7) signal` which has info on `pause`  and `sigsuspend`

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX clarifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) the behavior of SIGSTOP:  *Stop executing (cannot be caught or ignored).*

When you send your process a SIGUSR1, it then stops itself in the middle of its signal handler.  A subsequent USR1 or other signal is held pending on the stopped process until it is resumed.  You'll need to generate the SIGCONT externally, or rethink your design.